# How to disable new to Windows 10 WinKey hotkeys?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

I found that adding this line `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
NoWinKeys REG_DWORD 0x00000001 (1)` to registry removes only old combinations, win+e or win+d, but not win+i and win+k (Windows 10 specific combinations).

Ideally I would like to remove only some of them: win+k, win+l, win+i etc. I also tried solution from here http://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/22/how-to-disable-specific-global-hotkeys-in-windows/ (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced DisabledHotkeys REG_EXPAND_SZ KLI`) and it did not work at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas so far? :/

Comment: Quite frankly, I find it disgusting that Windows (and now Windows 10) provides no control panel to select and set the Windows hotkeys.

Answer (score 3):

I've always used Autohotkey to override Windows shortcuts.  If you want to disable them completely, your Autohotkey script could simply:

```
#k::return
#l::return
#i::return
```

I'm not entirely sure why you'd want to disable any of them (unless you're running some sort of kiosk on them).  I've always overwritten them:

```
#g::Run http://www.google.com/
#i::Run http://myiphomepage
```

Unfortunately on Windows 10, the Game Bar hooks into <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> outside of the normal operating system means, so you'll have to disable that inside of the Xbox App itself (very annoying).

Comment: I've been running into that problem with trying to override Win+G, and occasionally Win+Z also.  Thanks for the pointer to the Xbox App

Comment: In my case (with latest Win 10 and latest autohotkey), `#l::return` does not prevent default behavior, which is logout. So I had to disable logout option in the registry completely, then autohotkey is able to remap it (because default behavior is no longer available at all).

Comment: @Mihail How do you disable #L in the registry?

Comment: @Langdon Here `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` create a new DWORD 32-bit value named DisableLockWorkstation and give it `1`(disable) or `0`(enable)